# Change to QuickTime player in Mavericks?

Tags: audio, macos, quicktime

It appears Apple has changed the QuickTime player in Mavericks.
You can no longer extract music from a video.
Previously you could run a video and when you saved, it gave you an option for audio only. This seems to have disappeared.
Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The option to export the audio only has been moved to **File** → **Export** → **Audio Only…**

[image]